# How to remove a specific string common in multiple lines in a CSV file using shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, csv, awk, sed

I have a csv file which contains 65000 lines (Size approximately 28 MB). In each of the lines a certain path in the beginning is given e.g. "c:\abc\bcd\def\123\456". Now let's say the path "c:\abc\bcd\" is common in all the lines and rest of the content is different. I have to remove the common part (In this case "c:\abc\bcd\") from all the lines using a shell script. For example the content of the CSV file is as mentioned.

```
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.frag                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.vert                   0   0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.link-link-0.frag       16  24  3
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.link-link-0.vert       87  116 69
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin   75  95  61
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.link-link-0            0   0
C:/Abc/Def/Test/temp\.\test\GLNext\FILE0.link-link-6            0   0   0
```

In the above example I need the output as below

```
FILE0.frag                  0   0   0
FILE0.vert                  0   0   0
FILE0.link-link-0.frag      17  25  2
FILE0.link-link-0.vert      85  111 68
FILE0.link-link-0.vert.bin  77  97  60
FILE0.link-link-0               0   0
FILE0.link                  0   0   0
```

Can any of you please help me out with this?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include a few lines of example input and expected output? Is the common substring known in advance or should it be calculated from the input?

Comment: Without doing as @Wintermute suggests you are going to end up with an answer that may produce the output you want for some specific input set but is an absolutely ridiculous way to get it and probably won't work for all possible inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sed`:

```
$ cat test.csv 
"c:\abc\bcd\def\123\456", 1, 2
"c:\abc\bcd\def\234\456", 1, 2
"c:\abc\bcd\def\432\456", 3, 4

$ sed -i.bak -e 's/c\:\\abc\\bcd\\//1' test.csv

$ cat test.csv
"def\123\456", 1, 2
"def\234\456", 1, 2
"def\432\456", 3, 4
```

I am using `sed` here in this way:

```
sed -e 's/<SEARCH TERM>/<REPLACE_TERM>/<OCCURANCE>' FILE
```

where

- `<SEARCH TERM>` is what we are looking for (in this case `c:\abc\bcd\`, but backslashes need to be escaped).
- `<REPLACE TERM>` is what we want to replace it with, in this case nothing, and
- `<OCCURANCE>` is which occurance of the item we want to replace, in this case the first item in each line.

(`-i.bak` stands for: Don't output, just edit this file. (but make a backup first))

*Updated according to @david-c-rankin comment. He is right, make a backup before editing files in case you make a mistake.*

Comment: `sed -i.bak ... filename` stands for **edit `filename` in place**, but if I screw it up, please make a backup for me in `filename.bak`. It's always better to delete .bak files later...

Answer (score 0):

```
# init variable
MaxPath="$( sed -n 's/,.*//p;1q' YourFile )"
GrepPath="^$( printf "%s" "${MaxPath}" | sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' )"

# search the biggest pattern to remove
while [ ${#MaxPath} -gt 0 ] && [ $( grep -c -v -E "${GrepPath}" YourFile ) -gt 0 ]
 do
   MaxPath="${MaxPath%%?}"
   GrepPath="^$( printf "%s" "${MaxPath}" | sed 's#\\#\\\\#g' )"
 done

# Adapt your file
if [ ${#MaxPath} -gt 0 ]
 then
   sed "s#${GrepPath}##" YourFile
 fi
```

- Assuming for the sample that there is no special regex char nor # in MaxPath
- the `grep -c -v -E` is not optimized in term of performance (treat whle file each time where it can stop at first miss)